# How to use 'initWithSuiteName' from Cordova Plugin in Ionic4

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native, cordova-nativestorage

I want to share data between an Ionic4 app and a native today widget. For this, I'm using [this plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/)

In the documentation of the [Cordova plugin](https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage) you find "iOS-specific features" where the NativeStorage.initWithSuiteName is mention. But this is missing in the Ionic plugin.

So I changed my code like this:

```
if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
  window['plugins'].NativeStorage.initWithSuiteName('group.com.test.test');
}
```

and

```
this.nativeStorage.setItem(key, val);
```

But when I want to get the data in the today widget the key isn't set.

```
let preferences = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.test.test");

        if let test = preferences!.string(forKey: "test") {
            print(test);
        } else {
            print("No");
        }
```

Does anyone know how to handle this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If share data in same App ID, don't use `initWithSuiteName()`

`this.nativeStorage.setItem(key, val);`

```
if let test = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "test") as? String {
    print(test);
} else {
    print("No");
}
```

If share data between applications or extension, you need to use App Group
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_application-groups

before `setItem()`

```
if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
    NativeStorage.initWithSuiteName(APP_GROUP_ID);
}
```